# How could i declare this object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I like to delare array of this object, how could i do this in javascript?

```
student[0].name  
student[0].age
student[0].id

student[1].name  
student[1].age
student[1].id
```

Could someone please advise?

Comment: `student` is a collection, that is an array of objects. Better call it `students`.

Comment: possibly u may try: var students = []; students.push({"name": "Adam", "age" : 20, "id" : 1}); students.push({"name": "William", "age" : 21, "id" : 2});

Comment: thanks Arvind. it work. will accept your answer if you put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first declare an object

this don't need a studnet.js you can write the object on the same file.

```
var newStudent = new Object(); //Declare object

newStudent.name="foo";
newStudent.age=20;
newStudent.id=01

//declare array
var student = new Array();
student.push(newStudent);

//later loop array and you can read with
student[0].age
```

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
var students = [{ name: 'foo', age: 5, id: 1 }, { name: 'bar', age: 6, id: 2 }];
```

Comment: how do i declare in javascript? and can use it like students[0].name ='aa';

Comment: Yes, you can change name of first student that way. I suggest to read first about arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
var Student = function(n, a, i) {
    this.name = n;
    this.age = a;
    this.id = i;
};

var students = [];
students.push(new Student('foo', 12, 1));
students.push(new Student('bar', 13, 2));
students.push(new Student('baz', 14, 3));

console.log(students[0].name);
console.log(students[2].age);
console.log(students[1].id);
```

HTH